# QT5 Linguist macro in cmake

Tags: cmake, qt5.5, qt-linguist

despite being quite new to cmake, I succeeded to create a new project including `Qt5LinguistTools` and a .ts file containing my translations.
I added a section into my cmake file to call lupdate and lrelease on my file(s) using the defined macro `QT5_CREATE_TRANSLATION`.

It actually calls lupdate, with my ts-file and my other given options, but **always** also including the additional parameter

```
@<my_project_build_dir>/<tsfilename>_lst_file
```

(to tell lupdate additional source directories).
I assumed my source directory as content, but surprisingly it contains all Include paths used in the project:

E.g., as I also use boost library, my boost_dir is also included. This seems very strange to me.

I analyzed the macro, where the lst_file is being created, so for me it seems as a bug in the cmake macro.

How to I **disable this lst_file** without touching the macro from qt?

Answer (score 0):

The Qt-Macro obviously includes all the paths set via `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(...)`.
To avoid that, declare those paths via

`SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "")
target_include_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME} ... )`.